# Multiple threads increases wifi speed? Why?

Tags: android, multithreading, wifi

I used my laptop to set up a hostednetwork and tested the wifi speed between my laptop and my android phones. The two phones are the same by the way.

I first connect my laptop and one of my phone, and transmit a file of 400 Mb from laptop to phone and it took 169.6s on average.

Then, I connect my laptop with two phones and use two threads to transmit a file of 200 Mb to each phone respectively. So totally 400 Mb data is transmitted. And on average, it only took 136.2s, which is less than 169.6s.

My question is, since my laptop only have one wifi chipset, how can it be faster when I use two threads to transmit data of the same size? One thing I am sure is that it cannot be the interference from other wifi devices since it occurs all the time, even when there is no wifi devices around. Is it possible that when I did it using one thread, the computer didn't allocate all the wifi resources to that thread?

Comment: Since two threads are used, so more chances to access the resource are increased. More CPU cycles are consumed by these two threads hence more throughput you are getting. In short, now two process are running in parallel, so time consumption is reduced.

Comment: @GauravGupta: Since the two threads are accessing the same wifi chip, I think the wifi part is the bottleneck of data rate. And even the two threads are parallel, in the wifi chip it is not parallel because it cannot send packets from two threads simultaneously. I am not really sure if I am right though... Please let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: In case of single thread, when this thread is released from CPU, then your wifi chip would be idle. But in case of two thread chances are more that, when CPU releases one thread, thread2 may be picked up and then this thread2 will acquire wifi chip. This is why work done by wifi chip is more when multiple threads are there, since probability of execution of thread that will use wifichip increases.